# Working example of mediaelement.js flash fallback working on IE9

Tags: flash, internet-explorer-9, mediaelement.js, mediaelement, fallback

I basically can't get mediaelement.js working on IE9 (and, apparently, even mediaelement.js' home page can't seem to do it). A friend told me to look into forcing IE9 to fall back to flash, so I was hoping to find examples. That effort was both fruitless and futile. So any example site/page that shows that is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A little hacky, and won't work depending on what is on your page but you could do something like adding the following meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```

Which will force IE to render using IE8 standards, and hence, use flash. I know there's a better way, but if your in a jam, it's better than nothing and won't affect other browsers.

You may also check the compression of you videos/audio, as not all .mp4/.mp3 are created equal. I once had an issue where it wasn't playing in IE9, and a re-encoded video did the trick.